# Spinning progress bar in every listview item

Tags: android, listview, asynchronous, progress-bar, cycle

I've been scratching my head over this for a long time now and searched for an answer without any luck!
It seems to be trivial, but as far as I know, it isn't.

I use a listview in my Android application where every item (view) displays a spinning ProgressBar before the
content is loaded and displayed (the content is retrieved through http calls and json, so it may take a while to process).
The problem is that the spinning progress bars rotates independently of each other, thus creating the effect of a whirling
chaos instead of a syncronised row of good-looking loading markers.

I've tried everything i could come up with... not recycling the ProgressBar in getView()... have only one instance of the same ProgressBar...
resetting the ProgressBars android:progress whenever the list items gets visible (via onScroll() in the activity)... etc,
but since they start to spin in creation time (when getView gets called in the adapter) they will never have the same cycle sync.

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Great question! I'm curious myself.

Comment: (Just assumption) Possible, because of drawn listitem one by one on screen. First listitem's progressbar started first.

Comment: @ user370305 This has been explained in the question itself.

Comment: My previous answer was a bit buggy, just got it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT: Now works perfectly!*** - inserted animation listener call setStartOffset() back to 0 after the first repeat so that it doesn't keep "jumping" randomly.

---

I found a working solution for this issue, which works by timing the animation to the current system milliseconds. It's a bit of a hack, as it uses reflection to get the `mAnimation` field in `ProgressBar`. That being said, this field has remained in place in the Android sources since it was created (works up to 4.2).

Create the `android.widget.SyncedProgressBar` class, and use it instead of `ProgressBar` in your .xml files. It essentially makes the animation start at the beginning of the animation duration. You can also play around with `setDuration(500)` to verify that it works (the progress wheel will spin really quickly). Hope this helps!

```
package android.widget;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

/**
* @author Oleg Vaskevich
*
*/
public class SyncedProgressBar extends ProgressBar {

    public SyncedProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        modifyAnimation();
    }

    public SyncedProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        modifyAnimation();
    }

    public SyncedProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        modifyAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisibility(int v) {
        super.setVisibility(v);
        modifyAnimation();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onVisibilityChanged(View changedView, int visibility) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
        modifyAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        modifyAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setIndeterminate(boolean indeterminate) {
        super.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
        modifyAnimation();
    }

    public void modifyAnimation() {
        Field mAnim;
        try {
            mAnim = ProgressBar.class.getDeclaredField("mAnimation");
            mAnim.setAccessible(true);
            AlphaAnimation anim = (AlphaAnimation) mAnim.get(this);
            if (anim == null)
                return;

            // set offset to that animations start at same time
            long duration = anim.getDuration();
            long timeOffset = System.currentTimeMillis() % duration;
            anim.setDuration(duration);
            anim.setStartOffset(-timeOffset);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    animation.setStartOffset(0);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("SPB", "that didn't work out...", e);
            return;
        }
        postInvalidate();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to make it work. Use just one AnimationDrawable, multiplex the callback.
ProgressBar doesn't really add anything, you might as well stick with View.
Make a subclass of View that bypasses the Drawable management.

```
public class Whirly extends View
{
   Drawable image = null;

   public Whirly(Context context, AttributeSet attr)
   {
      super(context, attr);
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas)
   {
      if (image!=null)
         image.draw(canvas);
   }

   public void setImageDrawable(Drawable image)
   {
      this.image = image;
      invalidate();
   }
}
```

Then make your activity keep track of all the whirlies somehow.

```
public class Demo extends Activity implements Drawable.Callback
{
   private Handler h;
   private AnimationDrawable a;

   private Whirly w0;
   private Whirly w1;
   private Whirly w2;
   private Whirly w3;

   public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
      ...

      h = new Handler();

      a = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mywhirly);
      int width = a.getIntrinsicWidth();
      int height = a.getIntrinsicHeight();
      a.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

      w0 = (Whirly) findViewById(R.id.whirly0);
      w1 = (Whirly) findViewById(R.id.whirly1);
      w2 = (Whirly) findViewById(R.id.whirly2);
      w3 = (Whirly) findViewById(R.id.whirly3);

      w0.setImageDrawable(a);
      w1.setImageDrawable(a);
      w2.setImageDrawable(a);
      w3.setImageDrawable(a);

      a.setCallback(this);
      a.start();
   }

   public void invalidateDrawable (Drawable who)
   {
      w0.invalidate();
      w1.invalidate();
      w2.invalidate();
      w3.invalidate();
   }

   public void scheduleDrawable (Drawable who, Runnable what, long when)
   {
      h.postAtTime(what, who, when);
   }

   public void unscheduleDrawable (Drawable who, Runnable what)
   {
      h.removeCallbacks(what, who);
   }
}
```

Comment: I've been working on your code for a while now and i'm doing some progress, at least it seems to be the right direction :) The problem though, is that i'm having difficulties implementing this code in my adapter.. in your example, every "whirly" is already defined in some resource, and they all is set to use the same AnimationDrawable. I want to have only one whirly defined, that every list item in my listview will share.

Comment: In your ListView each item has to have a full layout with their own views. For each animated graphic you are going to need a view. A Whirly is just a very thin wrapper around the least expensive view (View). The item layout XML would just have a horizontal LinearLayout, a TextView for "Tues 1" and a Whirly. When an item is done you'd whirly.setImageDrawable(null) and take it off the callback list. onResume would a.start(), onSuspend would a.stop(), when the count of Whirlys on the callback list goes to zero a.stop();

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter getView() disable your progressViwe's, and then for each progressView

```
handler.postAtTime(new Runnable(){

public void run(){
     progressView.setEnabled(true);
}}, someTimeInTheFuture
);
```

What this will do is enable all your progressViews at the same time. This might work, i have not tested. If this does not work then you may want to add the progressView dynamically(not included in the layout, but add via addView()). But do so in the runnable, the key here is so they all get added at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the source code I see that the spinning image is a drawable that is spinning because of a private `Animation`. There is no way to obtain the view or the animation, thus discarding any idea I had of reusing one animation on all the views. I'd say your only alternative is what Jug6ernaut suggested, even though it is not the prettiest of solutions.

Comment: getIndeterminateDrawable works fine in any case. [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getIndeterminateDrawable%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible given that each row in your `ListView` is recycled when it moves off screen. When a new row appears on the screen the `ProgressBar` views will all have to be re-synchronized with each other. Keeping all of the rows in sync is going to be a big PITA.

Have you considered loading all of the list data in one request and caching that data to local storage? It would be much more efficient and result in a better user experience. It's not very useful to have a `ListView` that loads immediately with empty rows. I'd rather wait for the list to populate entirely.

Comment: Not that much of a PITA, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

1> Create Layout for list row

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/word_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Word 1" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/row_progress"
        style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/speaker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/speaker_icon" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

2> Then in getView method

```
if(word.getIsWordSynchedLocally() == 1){
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.speaker).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_progress).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.speaker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```